# Not able to login into Kylo

Tags: java, spring, kylo

When I'm trying to login into Kylo, it is throwing the following error,

```
2018-05-03 10:00:10 INFO  http-nio-8400-exec-6:JerseyRestClient:219 - Created new Jersey Client without SSL connecting to http://sdo-dbstore2:8400/proxy
2018-05-03 10:00:11 INFO  http-nio-8400-exec-6:JerseyRestClient:219 - Created new Jersey Client without SSL connecting to http://sdo-dbstore2:8400/proxy
2018-05-03 10:00:11 ERROR http-nio-8400-exec-6:JerseyRestClient:421 - Failed to process request org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder@24da432f
javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:1002)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:816)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$700(JerseyInvocation.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.rest.JerseyRestClient.get(JerseyRestClient.java:415)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.rest.JerseyRestClient.get(JerseyRestClient.java:387)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.rest.KyloRestLoginModule.retrieveUser(KyloRestLoginModule.java:220)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.rest.KyloRestLoginModule.doLogin(KyloRestLoginModule.java:122)
    at com.thinkbiganalytics.auth.jaas.AbstractLoginModule.login(AbstractLoginModule.java:84)
```

My application.properties uncommented part looks like,

```
spring.profiles.active=native,auth-kylo

## auth-file: If this profile is active then these optional properties may be used:
security.auth.file.users=file:///opt/kylo/current/users.properties
security.auth.file.groups=file:///opt/kylo/current/groups.properties
#security.auth.file.password.hash.enabled=false
#security.auth.file.password.hash.algorithm=MD5
#security.auth.file.password.hash.encoding=base64
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please set this configuration and restart `Kylo`. This assumes `Kylo` is installed at `/opt/kylo`.

**Kylo UI**

Add the `auth-file` profile to `spring.profiles`. Update the values for `security.auth.file.users` and `security.auth.file.groups` properties.

> File: /opt/kylo/kylo-ui/conf/application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=native,auth-kylo,auth-file
:
:
security.auth.file.users=file:///opt/kylo/users.properties
security.auth.file.groups=file:///opt/kylo/groups.properties
```

**Kylo Services**

Uncomment the `security.auth.file.users` and `security.auth.file.groups` properties. This section will look like:

> File: /opt/kylo/kylo-services/conf/application.properties

```
spring.profiles.include=native,nifi-v1.2,auth-kylo,auth-file,search-esr,jms-activemq,auth-spark
:
:
security.auth.file.users=file:///opt/kylo/users.properties
security.auth.file.groups=file:///opt/kylo/groups.properties
```

**Create users.properties file**

```
vi /opt/kylo/users.properties
```

Add this entry:

```
dladmin=thinkbig
```

Change ownership and permissions

```
chown kylo:users /opt/kylo/users.properties
chmod 600 /opt/kylo/users.properties
```

**Create groups.properties file**

```
vi /opt/kylo/groups.properties
```

Add these entries:

```
dladmin=admin,user
analyst=analyst,user
designer=designer,user
operator=operations,user
```

Change ownership and permissions

```
chown kylo:users /opt/kylo/groups.properties
chmod 600 /opt/kylo/groups.properties
```

**Restart Kylo UI and Services**

```
/opt/kylo/stop-kylo-apps.sh
/opt/kylo/start-kylo-apps.sh
```

Then, attempt to log in with `user=dladmin`, `password=thinkbig`

Comment: I tried changing the ownership of users.properties and groups.properties  file to kylo. But it says 'invalid user: kylo'

Comment: Are you using the Kylo Sandbox VM?

Comment: No, I'm using a VM on which Kylo is setup. So when you say kylo user on the Sandbox, are you referring to the root user on a normal VM?

Comment: If Kylo is to be installed on a VM (say HDP VM), then the installation guide must be followed. Creating 'kylo' user is one of the initial steps. Please refer to http://kylo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/CreateServiceAccounts.html, along with the rest of the installation instructions. To get up and running quickly, I would recommend using the Kylo Sandbox available at https://kylo.io/quickstart.html

Comment: is there anyway we can disable the kylo login??